# Redis and symfony PSR16 cache

Tags: php, symfony, caching, redis

I'm saving a value into Redis cache from a symfony application using `Symfony\Component\Cache\Psr16Cache` implementation. I do

```
$cache->set('key',[
    'value1' => (new \DateTime())->getTimestamp(),
    'value2' => (new \DateTime())->getTimestamp(),
    'value3' => 'message'
])
```

Obviously two `\Datetime`'s are different. What it does is kind of serialization of the array and datetime objects into string like :

```
127.0.0.10:6379> GET key
"\x00\x00\x00\x02\x14\x03\x11\x16value1\x17\bDateTime\x14\x03\x11\x04date\x11\x1a2019-09-25 09:12:00.000000\x11\rtimezone_type\x06\x03\x11\btimezone\x11\x10America/New_York\x11\x14value2\x1a\x01\x14\x03\x0e\x02\x11\x1a2019-09-28 20:39:00.000000\x0e\x04\x06\x03\x0e\x05\x0e\x06\x11\x13message\x11\x11message"
```

So it's type of string, not array.

Then I need to read this key from another app. This app uses [this Redis class](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis) and its [`hgetall`](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis#hgetall) call, which returns `(error) WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value` for the key I saved above from the other app.

Question: what call from Redis library should I use to get the array from the serialized value that PSR16 symfony implementation saved?

Comment: maybe a stupid question but you didn't call \DateTime constructor here, isn't it? something like `(new \DateTime())->getTimestamp()`

Comment: yes, sure, I just typed the code here manually, sorry, will update now. In the meantime I figured out that it's symfony's PSR16 component who prepends the data, probably to save the datatype of the cache value